# Why does SKAction.sequence not end properly after last Action shut it down?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I am trying to move a node from one Tile to other Tile. the Problem here is: If I run this, the position.y from node will some something like 63.9999 and not 64 if started at 32 and touched right after starting the Screen.

```
class A: SKScene {

       //Changed if screen Touched
       var abc = 0
       var node = SKSprideNode!

       override viewDidLoad() {
         node.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence(
                [
                    SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 32, duration: 1),
                    SKAction.run{
                        self.node.position.y = round(self.node.position.y)
                        if self.abc != 1 {
                            self.node.removeAllActions()
                        }
                    }
                ]
            )))
        }

        override func touchesBegan(...) {
        abc = 1
        }

        override update() {
          print(node.position.y)
        }

    }
```

Here the Output from the Console:

```
32.0
32.0
33.4936981201172
34.4316482543945
35.3333969116211
36.4936981201172
...
...
63.9936981201172
64.0
64.4936981201172
64.4936981201172
64.4936981201172
```

it should be 64.0 at the and, why is it not at 64.0?

Comment: is your sprite width/height an odd size?

Comment: No, like the tiles 32x32

Comment: ok, that may be why them,  center of your sprite is 15.5,15.5

Comment: How, should it not be 16, 16?

Comment: top left corner is 0,0  top right is 31,0

Comment: Sadly doesn't make any change.

Answer (score 0):

I want to use terms for the current iOS 9, swift 2.3.

From the Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/repeatActionForever:) :

> "The action to be repeated must have a non-instantaneous duration.".

When **runBlock** is executed an action take place instantaneously. So, you are not using `repeatActionForever` as it meant to be used.

You just need to add a slight delay to it and it should work. In fact, if you try to put a little wait in your sequence before your actions as this:

```
SKAction.waitForDuration(0.1),
SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 32, duration: 1),
SKAction.run{ ...
```

you should obtain 64.0 as you wish.

Comment: This should do it but the delay is really bad in Games if I want to move the Player.

Comment: @Lirf This delay is imperceptible. Anyway If you don't want it, you can change your code, don't put an action block to remove the node,  you can check abc status in your update method, (check if action is running) stop the action with a key name and (check if node exist) remove the node (it's a better way..)

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano, a delay shouldn't matter, we want instantaneous to happen,  the sequenced action together is not instantaneous,  the runblock should fire immediately after his move finishes, which we want, and we know this because his output shows it fires

Comment: The reason why you need non instant, is because an instantaneous action inside a repeatForever yields an infinite loop

Comment: It looks like there is no good chances to let a node move smooth that way. Are there a way in an sks file to add an action with variable positions?

Comment: Have you try the code I ve suggest in my answer? Because It works

Comment: I tried and 0.2 delay was safer. Only problem the Node has to move continiously without standing this 0.1 or more Delay time. Edit: and never stops if he moves until 32 pixels moved